# Will USB mouse with lights work in ps/2?

Tags: mouse

I have a USB mouse that lights up and has a couple extra buttons 
[https://www.amazon.com/Redragon-M602-NEMEANLION-Buttons-Backlighting/dp/B011HMDZ0Q](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B011HMDZ0Q)

My question is if I connect it to my ps/2 port will there be a problem with its lights? Will the port be able to provide the necessary power?
Thanks for any help...

Comment: PS/2 can output 275mA max. USB 2.0 devices have a consumption of anywhere from 100mA to 500mA. Without knowing the power consumption of that specific device, its hard to tell. Also, why hook up the mouse to PS/2 since the extra buttons wouldn't work.

Comment: Are you asking about a play station 2, or those round keyboard/mouse ports?

Comment: The round old school mouse/keyboard inputs

Comment: If you are connecting a usb to the round ps/2 ports, using an adaptor, then note: the adaptor does nothing, it will only work with duel protocol mice. If your mouse is not a usb/ps2 mouse then it will not work.

Comment: @richard is right, and I can confirm that this specific mouse does NOT support the PS/2 protocol. You'll have to stick with USB.

Comment: Having said what I said above about the adapter: note it is possible to get a usb to ps/2 (usb at computer to ps/2 at peripheral) adapter, that has active components. It will cost the price of several mice, and I have not seen one that does ps/2 to usb (the way that you need, though it should be possible).

Comment: Thanks everybody. I only ask because I've read that the ps/2 ports are faster and dedicated to keyboard/mouse, and figured I'd save my USB ports that way. I'm not a high performance gamer so in the end it doesn't really matter, but the searching I did couldn't answer my question specifically like you all did. So while it is possible for the ports to supply the requisite power to the mouse, the extra buttons will not work. I like the buttons. Deal breaker.